# NgbDropdown ng-bootstrap inside parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, ng-bootstrap

I have NgbDropdown like this

```
  <div ngbDropdown class="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <button class="btn" id="dropdownMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle
            dropdown</button>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
            <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
            <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
          </div>
   </div>
```

[image]

It work ok but when i have child component like this

**navbar.component.html**

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <button class="btn" id="dropdownMenu" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle
            dropdown</button>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
            <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
            <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
          </div>
   </div>
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

And i try to use in some parent component like **app.component.ts**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

It does not work, it does not  bind, console show no error and build it is working
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the navbar component needs `NgbDropdownModule` imported.
If this is the case you will see messages like "`ngbDropdown` is not known element" in the console

Comment: I have empty console

Comment: is it possible to make stackblitz? it would help for sure